# How to save a picture in app?

Tags: android

How can isave a picture that has been chosen from gallary. It loads fine but when i exit app it does not appear there anymore. I tried you using sharedpreferences by coping my code for saving text and this came up: Obviously that code i used for text doesnt work for images, i dont know. P.s i'm a beginner. thanks in advance

```
   import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContextWrapper;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;


public class Main extends Activity {


    private ContextWrapper context;
    private int imagebufferlength;
    private byte[] imagebuffer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);


        Button buttonLoadImage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonLoadPicture);
        buttonLoadImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                Intent i = new Intent(
                        Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                        android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

                startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
            }
        });;
```

***Here is your code you told me to put in. I had to make a lot of chnages like i said to revove the errors:***

```
File cacheDir = context.getCacheDir();
        File imageFile = new File(cacheDir, "image1.jpg");
        FileOutputStream out = null;
        try {
            out = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            out.write(imagebuffer, 0, imagebufferlength);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



            Button week1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.week1button);
            Button week2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.week2button);
        //Button Sound
        final MediaPlayer buttonSound = MediaPlayer.create(Main.this, R.raw.sound1);


        week1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                buttonSound.start();
                startActivity(new Intent("com.example.timetable.WEEK1"));
            }});

                week2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        buttonSound.start();
                        startActivity(new Intent("com.example.timetable.WEEK2"));
                    }
        });       

          };

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }




private static int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                    filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();

            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));

        }


    }
}
```

**However if i put it here it makes me do this and i get two erros that i canot slve my self:*

```
public class Main extends Activity {

private ContextWrapper context;
File cacheDir = context.getCacheDir();
File imageFile = new File(cacheDir, "image1.jpg");
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
out.write(imagebuffer, 0, imagebufferlength);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


    Button buttonLoadImage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonLoadPicture);
    buttonLoadImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            Intent i = new Intent(
                    Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                    android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

            startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
        }
    });;
```

Comment: Make sure you call `editor.commit();` after all you are done `put`ing values

Comment: The problem is when i use the text code for saving text it doesnt seem to workl with imageview's. It saids ImageView.BufferType isnt for image, only for text. And ImageView1).setSelection is for text only too. How can i use it for images or can i replace that?!?

Answer (score 0):

Why cant you store the image in application cache directory.

```
String cacheDir = context.getCacheDir();
File imageFile = new File(cacheDir, "image1.jpg");
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
out.write(imagebuffer, 0, imagebufferlength);
```

When ever u need to use this image, u can read from the cache directory and use it.

Please refer the below link for more info.

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html

Comment: I just tried it and i had to chnage it alot as came up with errors. i used the preset solutions. I ran the app and it wouldnt work. Said the app has stopped working. Wht should i do?

Comment: Ok I will do that in a couple hrs. Thanks

Comment: I have put the code in the original post. Have a look and tell me whats wrong.

Comment: Can you get back to me asap. Thanks